# How to limit creation of documents based on a field in another collection?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to limit the creation of documents based on a field in another collection, the main problem is when a client creates a document with another client at the same time, if for example, the field of **collectionA** has a field called **maxCreationOfDocuments: 2** I want that **collectionB** has only **2 documents**,  thus if **3** o more clients **create a document** in **collectionB** at same time I don't want that the three  more clients will create the document based on a field **collectionA   maxCreationOfDocuments: 2**. I tried to create a firestore rule but doesn't work.

```
match /squash/{squadId} {
  match /joined/{joinedId} {
   allow create: if request.query.limit <= 
 /databases/$(database)/documents/squash/{squadId}.data.maxUserJoined;
  }
}
```

Comment: *"the main problem is when a client join with other client at same time"*.  It's not clear to me what you mean by this.  Also, you should know that `request.query.limit` only applies to list requests, not writes.

Comment: Sorry I meant  the main problem is when a **client create a document with other client at same time**

Comment: I'm still not clear.  Maybe you could edit the question to illustrate the problem in more detail.  What queries are the clients performing that need to be controlled?

Comment: I edited the question only want limit the creation of documents in **collectionB** based in a field on **collectionA** called maxCreationOfDocuments: 2, I don't want perfom any query.

Comment: This is going to be difficult.  You can't count the number of documents in a collection in security rules, so you will need to maintain a count somewhere else, and compare against that count. Maintaining a count of documents is non-trivial.

Comment: :( ok I try another solution, Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Use a backend such as Cloud Functions to perform all the work securely.